# How fill QPixmap with uchar* array in PPM format

Tags: c++, qt

I generate array of dots colors in PPM format (255 255 255). How I can show it in pixmap?

If I fill pixmap with bluecolor (`m_pixmap.fill(Qt::blue)`) program draw for me a blue square, but when I trying load PPM image I get empty space without any image.

I am loading ppm in this way:

```cpp
ImageViewer::ImageViewer(QWidget * pi_parent)
  : QLabel{ QString{"ImageViewer" }, pi_parent }
  , m_pixmap{ 3, 2}
{
  m_pixmap.fill(Qt::blue);
  unsigned char data[] = {
    'P3',
    '3', '2',
    '255',
    '255', '0', '0',
    '0', '255', '0',
    '0', '0', '255',
    '255', '255', '0',
    '255', '255', '255',
    '0', '0', '0'
  };
  m_pixmap.loadFromData(data, sizeof(data), "PPM");
  this->setScaledContents(true);
  this->setPixmap(m_pixmap);
}
```

How I can set PPM image from array of colors? (without reading from file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must understand that PPM is text representation of some image. Now your `data` has been setup incorrectly that is why loading fails (missing spaces or line breaks makes this text unreadable).

it can go like this (using c++17 `std::string_view`):

```cpp
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

// this is a string view created from raw string literal
constexpr auto ppmImageData = R"(P3
3 2
255
255   0 0      0 255   0    0 0 255
255 255 0    255 255 255    0 0   0
)"sv;

ImageViewer::ImageViewer(QWidget * pi_parent)
  : QLabel{ QString{"ImageViewer" }, pi_parent }
  , m_pixmap{ 3, 2}
{
  m_pixmap.loadFromData(ppmImageData.data(), ppmImageData.size(), "PPM");
  this->setScaledContents(true);
  this->setPixmap(m_pixmap);
}
```

Dropping `std::string_view` (if you do not have C++17) is quite simple: just remove `sv` suffix and correct arguments of `loadFromData` invocation.

Comment: I could not repeat your example (R literal and sv not working in one time for me). But I add spaces and line breaks, separate P3 in two letters and it start working.
`unsigned char data[] = {
    'P','3','\n',
    '1', ' ', '1','\n',
    '255','\n',
    '25',' ', '0',' ', '0'
  };`

Comment: row literal is available since `C++11` (language feature). `sv` suffix since `C++17` (standard library feature, you need include `string_view` header).